# Change Bean name for Bean implementations packaged in Jar - Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

I am using spring boot and Autowired NamedParameterJdbcTemplate as

`@Autowired
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;`

I want to use different name for instance

```
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate myTemplate;
```

How can this be achived in spring boot as I dont I have access to implementation class as I am using spring JDBC in POM as dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring by default autowires the dependencies by Type reference not by name. Hence ur code will directly work without any changes required.

```
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate myTemplate;
```

Spring will look for a bean of type NamedParameterJdbcTemplate and Autowire it, unless u have explicitly specified autowired by name. In the case of autowireby name u can use the @Qualifier to specify the bean name to autowire.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("beanName")
```